# Getting conda to apply to python script called by other python script

Tags: python, module, conda

I have a script, A, that is importing another python script, B from the directory 'scripts'.

Both have the line :

```
from pymol import cmd, stored
```

And the conda environment I use to call script A has pymol activated.

However, pymol is failing to load within B, despite loading fine in A:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "A", line 7, in <module>
     import B
   File "scripts/B", line 6, in <module>
     from pymol import cmd,
stored ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymol'
```

I've tried adding pymol to the path in B with

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/path/to/mambaforge/envs/pymol/bin"))
```

but am still getting the same error.
My question is should I be expecting this to work? Or is there something I need to do that I don't realise in order to get a conda environment to apply to a python script called by another script within the desired environment?

Comment: To clarify, does script A also have a `from pymol import cmd, stored` prior to line 7 (`import B`), and it doesn't throw an error? How are you running the script?

Comment: Ah - so I moved `from pymol import cmd, stored` to before line 7 and the error is instead just being thrown from script A - there is an issue loading pymol generally rather than specifically for script B. 

Script A is being called on a HPC, first through a SLURM call to a bash script and then a Snakemake file - I still can't figure out why script A can't find pymol though.

Comment: Even having the line `print(os.environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV'])` in the script returns the the conda environment that is running pymol, and this same conda environment is allowing me to load pymol in when i call it from the command line, but something is happening when I call it as a SLURM job.

Comment: Generally, Snakemake is better to let it handle Conda environments itself (i.e., provide a `conda:` key to the rule with a YAML, not an existing environment). Otherwise, things that mess up activation are missing a `-l` in the shebang of the SLURM script, or not have `conda init` run for the user that executes the scripts. Sounds like the question here needs to be edited and a minimal example provided.

Comment: I'll also point out that `conda run` is so much better than mucking around with activating environments in a shell. That is, `conda run -n myenv python script_A.py` is better than `conda activate myenv && python script_A.py`. But again, if a Snakemake pipeline, then giving Snakemake a YAML and `--use-conda` is preferred as it is most reproducible.